# From a Batch file is there a way to retrieve some configuration info regarding Delphi?

Tags: delphi

From a standalone batch file, is there a way to retrieve some configuration info regarding Delphi? especially I would like to retrieve the path where is located the android SDK (api level, location of aapt.exe, etc.)

Comment: The first step is to find out where this information is stored. In a file? If so, what file format? In the registry? The second step is to write a batch script obtaining this information (which is not difficult, especially since a batch file can invoke a PS script). These are two separate issues.

Comment: If that information stored in the Registry (which I don't know), it is possible to do that.

Comment: @dummzeuch: INI and XML files aren't much harder.

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand yes in registry (example Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Embarcadero\BDS\22.0\PlatformSDKs) I will look if their is already ready made batch available somewhere

Comment: Use `reg.exe`. -

Comment: There are batch files in the GExperts sources that read from the registry, e.g. https://sourceforge.net/p/gexperts/code/HEAD/tree/trunk/BuildTools/doGetDelphiPath.cmd